# Situations of underpromoting the pawn

Tags: pawn-promotion, stalemate

I recently came across a wonderful article on Chess.com about under promotion of pawns. One of the situations is here:

```
[FEN "8/8/1KP5/3r4/8/8/8/k7 w - - 0 1"]
[Date "1895.??.??"]
[White "Saavedra, Fernando"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Setup "1"]
[FEN "8/8/1KP5/3r4/8/8/8/k7 w - - 0 1"]
[Plycount "13"]
[Sourcedate "2014.05.08"]

1.c7 Rd6+ 2. Kb5 Rd5+ 3. Kb4 Rd4+ 4. Kb3 Rd3+ 5. Kc2 Rd4
```

In the above game using Rook instead of Queen for promotion seems to win it for white.

*If white is promoted to Queen, then 6.. Rc4+ and Qxc4 is forced which will be a stalemate.*

How many other situations can we consider for the under promotion?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to these questions: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/725/what-are-some-examples-of-promoting-a-pawn-to-a-rook-or-bishop?rq=1

Comment: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/730/why-would-one-promote-a-pawn-to-a-knight?rq=1

Comment: Read up on the "Babson Task" -- a type of chess problem where white must force mate in x moves, and where black can defend by promoting a pawn. _For each piece that pawn can promote to, the only white move that wins is a promotion to the same piece_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my take on this question, since I find the other two answers lacking actual examples.

**Knight promotion**

In the situation below black has been trying to prevent white from promoting the pawn (white has earlier given up his rook for a black pawn). White manages to promote, but only one of the promotions secures a (tablebase) draw.

```
[white "Alexander Evdokimov"]
[black "Evgeni Ellinovich Sveshnikov"]
[event "56th Russian Championships, 2003"]
[fen "8/r3KP2/8/4k3/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Ke8 Ke6 2. f8=N+! {2. ... Ra8+ otherwise} 1/2-1/2
```

Here, white underpromotes to avoid stalemate.

```
[white "Iroda Khamrakulova"]
[black "Ekaterina Ubiennykh"]
[event "WJun Women, 2001"]
[fen "6r1/k1P5/P7/1K1R4/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rd8 {according to tablebases, Rd7 wins faster} Rxd8 {again, there are slower ways for black to lose} 2. cxd8=N! {stalemate if rook or queen is promoted, a draw if a bishop (wrong corner)} 1-0
```

In the situation below, white has just played Qg3. Black underpromotes to gain a tempo, as white threatens checkmate and fork rival king and queen.

```
[white "Zvonimir Mestrovic"]
[black "Svetozar Gligoric"]
[event "Hastings, 1971/72"]
[fen "7k/1p2Npbp/8/2P5/1P1r4/3b2QP/3q1pPK/2RB4 b - - 0 1"]

1. f1=N+! 0-1
```

In the position below, white underpromotes to deliver a checkmate.

```
[white "William Strum"]
[black "John McManus"]
[event "Eastern Open, 1997"]
[fen "8/p3R2P/1p4k1/6p1/2rB2KR/P1r5/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. h8=N+ 1-0
```

Last, but not least, a very neat opening trap. Black undepromotes to gain a tempo and subsequently win the white queen.

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 e5 3. dxe5 d4 4. e3 Bb4+ 5. Bd2 dxe3 6. Bxb4 exf2+ 7. Ke2 fxg1=N+ 8. Rxg1 Bg4+ 0-1
```

**Rook promotion**

Arguably, less spectacular than knight underpromotions. One would promote to a rook in order to avoid a stalemate (otherwise, anything a rook can do, a queen also can). Two examples from endgames below.

```
[fen "6k1/6P1/5K2/8/8/6P1/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. g4 Kh7 2. Kf7 Kh6 3. g8=R! {stalemate in case of queen promotion. Knight promotion would also win, but would take longer} 1-0
```

.

```
[fen "4r3/5RPk/5K2/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rf8 Rxf8 2. gxf8=R {stalemate in case of queen promotion, unable to win if promoting to a minor piece} 1-0
```

**Bishop promotion**
These are the rarest of the bunch. Usually would be to avoid a stalemate, or some other extraordinary situations, since otherwise, anything a bishop can do, a queen also can. First, a classic.

```
[fen "4Q3/Pq4pk/5p1p/5P1K/6PP/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. a8=B! {promoting to rook or queen runs into Qf7+ and stalemate} 1-0
```

Another endgame.

```
[fen "8/8/5b2/8/K7/4N3/kp6/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Nd1 b1=B! {Nc3+ if promoting to rook or queen - draw} 0-1
```

Lastly, this amazing position.

```
[fen "1r5K/6PP/8/8/8/1k4q1/6P1/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. g8=B+! {black must move the king and it is a stalemate} Kb4 (1... Rxg8+ 2. hxg8=Q+ Qxg8+ 3. Kxg8 {and the g2 pawn will inevitably promote - white wins}) 1/2-1/2
```

**Sources for these and many more examples**

http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/minor.htm

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1000028

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more **extreme** situations to consider. The first two diagrams are merely for completeness.

```
[Title "Grigory Popov, 1st-5th Prize, Vladislav Tarasiuk-50 JT 2018, Mate In 33"]
[FEN "5B2/PPPPPPPP/q7/3rppp1/2p4p/3p3n/5p2/3N1Kbk w - - 0 1"]

1. a8=Q! Qa5 2. Qxa5 Rxa5 3. b8=Q Ra1 4. Qa8+ Rxa8 5. e8=Q Ra1 6. Qa8+ Rxa8 7. Ba3 Rxa3 8. g8=Q Ra1 9. Qa8+ Rxa8 10. c8=Q Ra1 11. Qc6+ e4 12. Qa4 Rxa4 13. h8=Q Rb4 14. Nc3 Rb2 15. d8=Q Re2 16. Nxe2 dxe2+ 17. Kxe2 Kg2 18. Qa1 Nf4+ 19. Kd2 f1=N+ 20. Kc3 Ne2+ 21. Kxc4 Be3 22. f8=Q Neg3 23. Qfa3 Nd2+ 24. Kb5 Bf4 25. Qd1 Ndf1 26. Qa2+ Nd2 27. Qaxd2+ Bxd2 28. Q8xd2+ Kh3 29. Qf2 e3 30. Qxe3 f4 31. Qf2 Nf1 32. Qdf3+ Ng3 33. Q2g2#
```

Source: [The Die Schwalbe Chess Problem Database](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/1381570)

```
[Title "Karlheinz Bachmann, Die Schwalbe 4/1998, Mate In 9"]
[FEN "8/PPPPPP2/7K/4rP2/8/6Pp/4Nprp/5Qnk w - - 0 1"]

1. e8=R Rxf5 2. f8=R Rc5 3. c8=R Ra5 4. a8=R Rd5 5. d8=R Rb5 6. b8=R Rh5+ 7. Kxh5 Rxg3 8. Nxg3#
```

Source: [The Die Schwalbe Chess Problem Database](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1008344)

```
[Title "David Zimbeck, Die Schwalbe 2/2003, Mate In 6"]
[FEN "5bbk/PPPPPB1p/4p2N/4p1PN/1q2P1R1/R4K2/3r4/6BQ w - - 0 1"]

1. exf8=B Qxf8 2. d8=B Rxd8 3. cxd8=B Qxd8 4. b8=B Qxb8 5. axb8=B Bxf7 6. Bxe5#
```

Source: [The Die Schwalbe Chess Problem Database](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1255069)

```
[Title "Andre Cheron, Journal de Geneve 2/4/1964, Mate In 8"]
[FEN "N7/PPPPPPPP/K1k3rB/b1pnnb1p/8/1r6/pp3p2/7q w - - 0 1"]

1. b8=N+ Rxb8 2. axb8=N+ Kd6 3. c8=N+ Ke6 4. d8=N+ Bxd85. exd8=N+ Kf6 6. g8=N+ Rxg8 7. hxg8=N+ Kg6 8. f8=N#
```

Source: [The Die Schwalbe Chess Problem Database](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.deP1294157/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but those positions are practically impossible I would say.