# Why is there an option for the pawn to be promoted in any chess piece?

Tags: pawns, pawn-promotion, pawn-endgame

A pawn can be promoted to a **queen**, a **knight**, a **rook** or a **bishop**. My question is why would someone want their pawn to be promoted to anything other than a queen? I can understand the knight promotion since their unconventional movement can lead to a sophisticated check mate, but other than that why would anyone promote their pawn to a rook or a bishop, since a queen can be both?

Are there any known occurrences where a player has promoted his/her pawn not to a queen?

Comment: Another http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9354/situations-of-underpromoting-the-pawn/9367#9367 and yet another http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/730/why-would-one-promote-a-pawn-to-a-knight question on same topic.

Comment: Underpromotion is done to prevent stalemate. You promote to a rook / knight / bishop to dodge stalemating your opponent.